# Debug native Android application

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I'm trying to learn the debug module 'Debug as Android Native Application'. I use the demo 'hello-jni'. I set a breakpoint in the cpp file.

Anyway, when I excute the 'Debug as Android Native Application', there comes errors.
The console says:

```
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Android
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] NDK:
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] WARNING:
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] APP_PLATFORM
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] android-14
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] is
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] larger
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] than
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] android:minSdkVersion
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] 3
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] in
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] ./AndroidManifest.xml
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] 
armeabi
[2013-08-09 16:51:12 - HelloJni] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

I'm new on this. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You might have not downloaded API-14 sdk.

In Eclipse Goto-- Window> Android SDK Manager  and check whether APi-14 is downloaded or not.

Comment: Thx. I've download the API-17, is that ok?

Comment: either change api level from 14 to 17 in AndroidManifest.xml   or download api-14